# jQuery unbind with document.on?

Tags: jquery, dom, unbind

My button is firing twice. Other SO posts say to unbind the click function from the  document. The problem is that the HTML elements are being dynamically appended to the document, so i need to call:

`$(document).on("click", "#id", function())`

But how to I "unbind" the click function from a document.on statement?

Here's my full code:

```
//Add Column
$(document).on("click", ".btn-add-tbl-col", addColumn); 

function addColumn() {

    console.log("addColumn fired!");  //Console shows this statement twice when I click the button once

    //Identify the table into cache
    var $tbl = $("#main-tbl-sch-tbl");

    //Count the number of records
    var rows = $tbl.find("tr.record").length;

    var columns = $tbl.find("th.tbl-column").length;
    columns++;

    var newCol = "<th class='tbl-column' data-id='0'>*Click*</th>";
    $(newCol).insertBefore($tbl.find("th.no-click-last"));

    $tbl.children("tbody.tbody-records").children("tr").each(function () {
            var $td = '<td class="record-cell" data-id="0" data-isstatic="1" data-col="' + columns + '" data-row="' + rows + '" data-colID="0" data-rowID="0" data-asid="0" data-deid="0" data-isnull="1" data-nameid="0" data-tbllookupid="0" data-collookupid="0" data-munterspn="0">*Click*</td>';
            $(this).append($td);
    });

    var newTableWidth = parseFloat((167 * columns) + 33 + 33);
    $tbl.css("width", newTableWidth.toString() + "px");
}
```

**FYI:  There is no other click function binded to the class**

Comment: When is the delegate event handler being created?

Comment: I have a select box onChange event that makes an AJAX call to retrieve the* HTML. The HTML is appended to another DIV element.

Comment: So how many times are you executing the logic that creates the delegate event handler?

Comment: This code is on the main page and is not being repeatedly appended - if thats what you are asking.

Comment: For it to execute multiple times, that suggests multiple bindings

Comment: Ok. I guess I have to dig more. Thank you

Comment: Before unbinding (`off`) I would recommend looking in your code to see WHY it's triggering twice as unbinding it won't fix the real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unbind the event the same way you binded it, but with off() method.

http://api.jquery.com/off/

So per documentation you need:

`$(document).off('click', '#id').on("click", "#id", function())`

In your exact problem you need:

`$(document).off("click", ".btn-add-tbl-col").on("click", ".btn-add-tbl-col", addColumn);`

Comment: This does not address the root issue, of why the event is firing twice.  That is the **real** question.

Comment: True, but from the shown code we can't say what triggers it twice

Comment: Which is why we ask for more information.  This is an example of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  The user is asking us about a problem with a solution to their problem.  Not about the actual problem itself.  We need to address the real problem.